# CSV parsing with groovy script using apache-nifi

Tags: csv, parsing, groovy, apache-nifi

I have a csv file with more than 70 columns and millions of records. But for processing I need around 20 columns. To extract them I have used modified `groovy` script in [Split fields and NiFi API with Groovy](http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-explained-split-fields.html).

My script :

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
   inputStream.eachLine { line ->
   a = line.tokenize(',')
   outputStream.write("${a[0]},${a[1]},${a[2]},${a[3]},${a[4]}\n".toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
   }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Original csv :

```
date,id,name,age,addr,lang
19/12/2019,1,sachith,29,sac@email,go
,2,nalaka,29,nalaka@email,
,,muhandiram,,c
```

When this is being processed by `ExecuteScript` processor, output looks like :

```
date,id,name,age
19/12/2019,1,sachith,29
2,2,nalaka,29
null,null,muhandiram,null
```

If data field is empty, its replaced with `id` and other empty values are replaced with `null`.

Why script misbehaves?
My knowledge about `groovy` is almost nothing.

expected output :

```
date,id,name,age
19/12/2019,1,sachith,29
,2,nalaka,29
,,muhandiram,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually your code is Ok, except `tokenize`

the [`tokenize`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#tokenize(java.lang.Character)) method does not return empty tokens.

use [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) instead of `tokenize` to have all values between delimiters.

for example following code:

```
println ",,2,3,,".tokenize(',')
println ",,2,3,,".split(',')
println ",,2,3,,".split(',',-1)
```

prints:

```groovy
[2, 3]
[, , 2, 3]
[, , 2, 3, , ]
```

> Note, that `split` without `-1` trims last empty tokens...

So, your code bit modified:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    outputStream.withWriter("UTF-8"){ w ->
        inputStream.eachLine("UTF-8"){ line ->
            def row = line.split(',',-1)
            w << row[0..4].join(',') << '\n'
        }
    }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Edit :
For someone who needs to take various random columns. Have to modify :

`w << row[col0,col3,col5,col10,col21].join(',')`